# Micronaut maven plugin dev mode issue with finding beans

Tags: java, maven, micronaut

I have a Micronaut project setup consisting of two modules. "domain" module contains all the domain code, the other one "web" mainly controllers, views etc. Web module includes domain as a compile dependency.

When packaging web module, everything is properly compiled and I can execute the final jar, application works as expected.

When executing using micronaut maven plugin, e.g. `mvn -pl web mn:run`, application starts but at runtime I get NoSuchBeanException for beans defined in domain module.

Comment: Hi. I tested this case both with Micronaut 3.9.4 and 4.0.2, and cannot reproduce this. I tested this by adding a bean annotated with `@Context` to the domain module, and when starting the app using `mvn -pl web mn:run`, the `@PostConstruct` in this bean was executed. Please provide code for a minimal app to reproduces this issue. BR

Comment: @RoarS. thank you, this helped me figure out my silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake on my side. I had `@Requires(env="local")` set on some beans and  run configuration in Intellij was specifying it, but I forgot to set the config when starting application in shell.

The command should have been `mvn -pl web mn:run -Dmicronaut.environments=local`